# paypal subscription not working on live mode

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

I have setup paypal subscription for my website,two types of subscription are there.It works fine in sandbox (test mode)  but not on live mode. when user proceed to pay through paypal by entering paypal email and password it shows "The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again".

The code i am using is

```
echo '<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">';
         echo '<input type="hidden" name="business" value="sales@example.com">';

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=" '.$ite_name.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="'.time().'" />';
        echo '<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="'.$sub[1].'">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="'.$sub[0].'">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1000000000'.$insert_id.'">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/manage/PNS-Manager/register.php?l=s" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://example.com/manage/PNS-Manager/cancel.php" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://example.com/manage/PNS-Manager/IPN.php" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo "<script> document.forms[0].submit();</script>";
```

Anybody have any idea whats the problem..???? please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the string of what you are passing over for these values, so that we can try testing it and see what's causing the error.  It may be an issue with one of the values you are setting for the variables.  Also, when switching to live, make sure that you change the business variable from your sandbox account to your live account.

Comment: thanx for replying...now the problem is sort out...thnx again

Comment: Hi i have same problem can you tell me how you have solved it